# Is there anything like live CD for android phones?

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, bootloader

We can go into recovery mode in android phones, which is usually home+volume up+power for samsung phones

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50899/37436) says that the recovery mode is like a simple OS that the device boots into. This OS then is not restricted by protections and folder permissions implemented by android, so it can see root folders and write to it if needed. I have also once seen (not sure of all the steps I did but I remember doing it) that a zip file in the sdcard root can be used to temporarily change this recovery screen software to something else (I think it was CWM recovery zip file, but it was the type where once you restarted the phone and went to recovery mode again, you would have to run the zip file again to get back to CWN recovery screen. There was a way to permanently replace the recovery screen with a CWM recovery but I didn't try it)

If that is the case, is there anything like a live CD for android? preferably also with a touch screen gui, and able to install and run apps from the phone's internal memory or sdcard? Has this been done or is it technically unfeasible? Would it have to be separately made for different phones?

Comment: Unlikely. There's no such thing like a "generic Android version" that fits all devices, see [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) – so that "Live CD" must be made for each brand/model specifically. Which is more effort than the results are worth.

Comment: i know what cwm you mean - it was a flashable zip signed with leaked samsung oem key which booted into temporary cwm session from "apply sdcard update.zip" in stock recovery. But this worked only for older Samsung devices like Samsung Galaxy Y Duos GT-S6102 with Android 2.3.6 and the zip files were always device specific, because each device requires his own kernel. a common standard for installing apps is a flashable zip. but the user need a custom recovery for this